# Using FAST Is there a way to apply styles to child ShadowDOM elements?

Tags: performance, shadow-dom, fast-ui

I've been working with the FAST toolkit (https://fast.design) creating my own elements that I wish to use. Part of that journey has lead me to make a `Toolbar`.

Been a `Toolbar`, I want to change the background of the buttons to be transparent (going for a look like: https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/components/toolbar/definition. Now I could create another element, i.e. `ToolbarButton` that extends `Button` (and any other controls which need the background removed) and it'll work for my purpose. Still, it feels like something I should be able to do as it's a unique trait of the `Toolbar`.

I'm not sure if it's even possible, but I can't figure it out looking through the documentation and source code on GitHub.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/fast/issues/3548

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great question. Fortunately, shadow dom itself supports a CSS feature for exactly this scenario. You can use the `::slotted` selector in the CSS for your toolbar to select particular elements that are slotted into the toolbar's slots and apply custom styles to them. So, you could target a button that is slotted into the toolbar and use that to set a css property on the button, or apply styles directly to it or its CSS parts. Here's the link to the MDN docs on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

Here's some sample css based on your scenario.

```
::slotted(fast-button) {
  --accent-fill-rest: transparent;
}
```

Remember, this must go into the toolbar's css to affect all `fast-button` elements that get slotted into the toolbar's slots.